# How to understand "implementations of virtual constructors" in Effective C++

Tags: c++, effective-c++

In Effective C++ 3rd, Item 31, p146-p147, it says

> That all happens behind the scenes inside the files containing the implementations of virtual constructors.

I'm not sure how to understand virtual constructors in this sentencen.

As far as I know, there is no virutal constructor in C++.

So, is this statement a mistake in Effective C++?

Or, does this virtual constructors refers to other things?

Comment: For those of us who don't have the book, what is the context?

Comment: That's just factory method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I know, there is no virutal constructor in C++.

Correct.

> So, is this statement a mistake in Effective C++?

No.

> Or, does this virtual constructors refers to other things?

It's just a common name for a design pattern which results in code that works like a "virtual constructor" would work, if it existed. Instead of saying "*a mechanism which works as if the constructor was virtual, even though it technically isn't"*, we simply say *"virtual constructor"*.

Another common name for the same pattern is "factory method".